# '=>' expected. TS1005 for Redux Action Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, interface, react-redux

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, below is a screenshot of the error I'm getting from esLint in Typescript:

[image: Error Shown in context]

The code itself is below, this is the entire file, is there something I'm doing wrong? This is supposed to be actions for some redux, but I may not know enough about the typescript syntax to figure out why it's giving me this warning, or how to get around it without doing a @ts-ignore, but that seems like a cop out. All of the other questions on here about the TS1005 error I've found don't really apply to this situation that I've seen.

Here's the full code:

```
interface ISignIn {
    (credentials: {email: string, password: string}): (dispatch: Function, getState: Function, getFirebase: any)
};

export const SignIn: ISignIn = (credentials) => {

    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            credentials.email,
            credentials.password
        ).then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' });
        }).catch((error: any) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', error });
        });

    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It should be a `type`, not an `interface`. After that, replicate the same arrow function syntax you have in your actual function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add return type of your async action. E.g.:

```
(credentials: {email: string, password: string}): (dispatch: Function, getState: Function, getFirebase: any) => void
```